# how to hide field from pydantic field but still can access

Tags: pydantic

User object has `p` and `h` field, I need to initial this two field.

```
class User(BaseModel):
    p: str
    h: str = Field(hidden=True)
    #_g: str = PrivateAttr()
    @staticmethod
    def schema_extra(schema: Any, _):
        print('HERE NOT WORK!')
        props = {}
        for k, v in schema.get('properties', {}).items():
            if not v.get("hidden", False):
                props[k] = v
        schema["properties"] = props
    model_config = ConfigDict(json_schema_extra=schema_extra)

s = User(p='1',h='2')
```

I don't want to return `h` when using `s.model_dump()`

and still need to acces `h` in my code `s.h`

I hope return json is `{'p':'1'}`

`print('HERE NOT WORK!')` not work , that is strange.

pydantic==2.5.2

pydantic_core==2.14.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seems you want to just use the `Field(exclude=...)` option:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field

class User(BaseModel):
    p: str
    h: str = Field(exclude=True)


s = User(p="1", h="2")
print(s.model_dump())
print(s.h)
```

Which prints:

```
{'p': '1'}
2
```

I hope this helps!